# Any zipping software that uses Trusted Timestamps with encryption

Tags: security, encryption

There are several zipping software that allow users to encrypt their data before zipping. Do any of these use Trusted Timestamps to set an expiration date for decryption?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping

Comment: Trusted timestamps don't set an expiration date for decryption. To do that, you need some trusted entity that will perform some operation up to a particular date and then will refuse to do it.

Comment: But they way they would do it is by issuing a trusted timestamp, right? Are there any encryption tools that offer this at encryption time? I guess zipping could be preformed independent of encryption.